# Do I need to have oracle software in my machine for migrating data from oracle to sql azure using SSMA?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, azure-sql-database

Do I need to have oracle software in my machine for migrating data from oracle to sql azure using SSMA?

Error  Message is like ...

**Connection to Oracle failed.
System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install oracle client from this link

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html

and chose 32-bit or 46-bit version to be able to connect to oracle DB